# What number am I thinking of?

Tags: mathematics

Adding an odd number would make an even number. It's not the largest prime number. But when you divide it into parts I make a multiple of 2. the range never exceeded 100 but never to less from 30. Figure me out

Comment: It's an odd number between 30 and 100, it's a multiple of 2 and it isn't prime?

Comment: I am voting to close because question is not clear. Title, tag, and description are inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not a number.
Your an *odd* number between 30 and 100, that is a multiple of *2*, so either your a magical wizard dragon, or NaN.

Comment: When I say I'm not the Largest Prime number doesn't it also tells you that I might not be a prime number at all. muhahahahahha(evil laughter)

Comment: @3.14159 you're still `NaN`, which is prime anyway.

Comment: You sir is hard to trick.

Comment: NaN is prime? The definition of a prime number is any integer greater than 1 with it's only factors being 1 and itself. If NaN is *Not a Number* how can you say it can be divided by 1, or even that it's greater than 1?

Comment: I didn't know that I thought a prime number was something divisible by 1 and itself, or nothing...